# Replaced 2 hallway light fixtures but now the light bulbs stay on dimly, even with its off

Tags: electrical, light, fixtures

So I had two very old light fixtures in my hallway with 2 switches at each end, and either switch would turn on or off both fixtures. Just replaced the light fixtures and put in LED lights, hooked up presumably exactly the same as prior fixtures but now......the lights won't turn  off completely, staying slight dim. What's wrong?

Comment: Are the switches lighted? Something is running a bit of current through the lights when the switch is off - a lighted switch is a typical example. On an incandescent bulb, you would see no light from the tiny current. On an LED you do.

Comment: Anything special about the switches? Besides lighted switch, some dimmers, smart switches, motion sensors, etc. can all have strange effects with LEDs.

Comment: Are these fixtures integral LEDs, or are they light-socket fixtures with LED bulbs screwed in?

Comment: Some LED bulbs contain a phosphor to reduce flickering. That can continue to glow for a while even after power has been removed from the bulb.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this really inductive/capacitive coupling, and is this remediation practical?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/57578/is-this-really-inductive-capacitive-coupling-and-is-this-remediation-practical) there are suggestions there on what to do, or you can get different LED bulbs